# Rectifiable set under diffeomorphism

Tags: measure-theory, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, lebesgue-measure, diffeomorphism

We need to show that image $f(A)$ of a rectifiable set $A$, under a diffeomorphism $f$, is also rectifiable.

Definition: A rectifiable set is a set which is closed, bounded & has boundary of measure $0$.

Approach:
It is easy to show that $f(A)$ is closed & bounded. Also, I can show that a measure $0$ set under a diffeomorphism has measure $0$.
I am confused if these two arguments enough. As the set $A$ has boundary of measure $0$ and the diffeomorphism $f$ would take the boundary $B$ to $B'$. And I can show measure of $B'$ is $0$. Now the problem is is it confirmed that $B'$ is the boundary of $f(A)$?

Comment: I'll assume $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. If $f$ is a homemorphism from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to itself, then $bf(A) = f(bA)$,

Comment: @Mason can you provide a short proof for the same?

Comment: Show that $f(x) \in bf(A) \iff x \in bA$. The proof is 3 lines. Use the fact that $f^{-1}$ distributes over union.